# No connection could be made error with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to launch Firefox driver by providing user profile from "C:\Users\HPME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" but getting the below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)
```

The Firefox browser window is launched but unable to proceed further due to the exception thrown.

Below is the code snippet for what I have been trying to do:

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("-profile","Existing Profile Path");
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options); //exception is thrown at this line after browser window is launched
```

Please help in identifying what am I doing incorrect or any additional settings I am missing.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: Can you reach the the url without using this specific Firefox profile? Can you reach the url at all?